# Replace maximum value of each column

Tags: r

I have a matrix where I want to replace maximum value of each column by -1.  How can I do it in R?
I tried,

```
 set.seed(14)
 mat<- matrix(sample(10,20,replace=TRUE),nr=5)
 apply(mat,2,which.max)
 [1] 3 2 1 4
```

I don't know how to replace the matrix.  How do I deal with duplicate max value within column?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
 mat[which(apply(mat, 2, function(x) x == max(x,na.rm=TRUE)))] <- -1
```

Comment: I'd use `==`, not `%in%`. It's faster.

Comment: Is there a "row" version of this?

Comment: @Tom It is an old post.  If you need the same syntax, may be change `apply(mat, 2` to `apply(mat, 1`.  Or another option is `library(matrixStats); mat[mat == rowMaxs(mat)] <- -1`